# Alternative for Math.round()

Tags: javascript, html, rounding

In JavaScript when value is 4.3, i want it to round off to 4 and if value is 4.5 or above it rounds off to 5. I want all this without using `Math.round()`.

Comment: What is wrong with Math.round()?

Comment: its a task that we have to do without using math.round

Comment: This can be achieved using other functions in Math, or using string formatting.

Comment: Plzz tell me how can i do using string formatting, but we have to do it without using math functions

Comment: @FarhanRamzan Split you number based on dot(.), then check for the second half of dot(.). if the 2nd half value is less than 5 then keep the 1st half as it is. If 2nd half is more than 5 then +1 to the 1st half .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this

```js
function RoundNum(number){
    var c = number % 1;
    return number-c+(c/1+1.5>>1)*1
}

console.log(RoundNum(2.456));
console.log(RoundNum(102.6));
console.log(RoundNum(203.515));
```

Comment: this is working till only 3 digits if you add 10354.6 it will not work

Answer (score 6):

You could also do this:

```
round=num=>(num-~~num>=0.5?1:0)+~~num;
```

Explanation:

```
~~num
```

is a double bitwise OR, actually it removes everything behind the point so 1.5 => 1

```
num-~~num
```

gets the distance to the next lower integer, so e.g. 5.4 => 0.4, 5.6 => 0.6

Some testcases:

http://jsbin.com/gulegoruxi/edit?console

Comment: Can you please explain what s happening here? Never seen `~~` before

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: You can also use `n|0`instead of `~~n` to truncate the number. Please note that truncating only works if `n` doesn't exceed 2^31-1.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could transform the number into a string, split it, and round it with the help of a ternary operator.

Example:

```js
// Decimal number
let number = 4.3;

// Convert it into a string
let string = number.toString();

// Split the dot
let array = string.split('.');

// Get both numbers
// The '+' sign transforms the string into a number again
let firstNumber  = +array[0]; // 4
let secondNumber = +array[1]; // 3

// Now you can round it checking the second number
let rounded = secondNumber < 5 ? firstNumber : firstNumber + 1; // 4
```

### In one line of code

```js
let rounded = +number.toString().split('.')[1] < 5 ? +number.toString().split('.')[0] : +number.toString().split('.')[0] + 1;
```