# Write a function that returns the square of a number without using *,+ or pow

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers

The task is to write a function that takes n as an input where n is a number (from -32768 to 32768) and returns the square of that number. Simple task except for the fact that we cannot use any operators such as *,+ or even use any Math. functions such as pow. eval is not allowed as well. 
Even more challenging is that we must keep the character code count **less than 39 characters**.

I absolutely cannot think of a way to get the square of a number without using the + or *. And even worse, to keep the character count less, it's impossible for me.

Codes like this won't work because: I used the plus sign and the character count is more than 60.

```
function sq(n){
   var res=n;
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
   res+=n;
return res;
}
```

If n is a decimal, we are expected to return the nearest whole number as the result.
Thank you for reading all of this!

Edit: My problem has been solved. Thank you to everyone who has tried to help me with their codes as it helped me gain a new aspect of solving each problems. 
Thank you very much again!

Comment: `we cannot use any operators such as *,+` Are those operators the only ones forbidden? What exactly is forbidden (or, what is permitted)?

Comment: `**2` is, technically, not the same as `*` is it allowed?

Comment: seems better asked at [codegolf.se]

Comment: @MattEllen This is my very first time on stackoverflow so I'm very sorry for the inconveniences if I came to the wrong part

Comment: No worries, just thought you might find a more receptive crowd over there

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg Sorry for the late reply, but it is not allowed as well. But no worries adiga have solved the problem along with Jaromina something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide `n` by `1 / n`

For rounding off without using `Math.round`, I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44985903/3082296):

```js
s=n=>(r=>(r-~~r<.5?0:1)- -~~r)(n/(1/n))

console.log(s(5));
console.log(s(4.4));
console.log(s(-4.44));
```

This has 39 characters.

Comment: This is the closest one omg, I just remembered that we can use negative powers but the last problem is that it does not round to the nearest whole number

Comment: As already mentioned above, we must not use any math functions to round the number to the nearest integer

Comment: @Dazzler it's not throwing any error for using `parseInt`

Comment: if limiting to 32 bit numbers isn't an issue ... `s = n => (n/(1/n))|0`

Comment: Really got even closer but using parseInt doesn't seem to round up to the nearest integer.Some answer is always 1 number away from each other.
Example, expected:  540533658, instead got: 540533657 
Something like that

Comment: You'd want `Math.round` then

Comment: We cannot use Math.round

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't see that

Comment: @Dazzler updated with an alternative to `Math.round`

Comment: @adiga - I removed my poorly thought out comment :p that's beautiful code :p

Comment: @adiga this is perfect. Seems to run normally but it doesn't seem to run on the website but I'd still rate it as a perfect answer

Comment: it wants the code to be 39 characters when it's only like 41 characters for the code you've written

Comment: @Dazzler it has 39 characters now. [It's working for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpZN.png)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you very much, doesn't seem to work for me yet probably because of my mistakes but if you got it right, I will probably get it right as well!

Comment: I totally don't understand how that rounding works but I will definitely try to learn them

Comment: @Dazzler it's taken from another answer. Click the link the answer

Comment: @JaromandaX those 2 characters you saved were crucial haha. (The second one won't work because can't use `+` sign)

Comment: I'm so slow tonight @adiga :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have tried done everything but I can't seem to solve the problem yet because it says that I've input in 40 characters, also in your image, the name of the function was s and not sq. For my part, it doesn't seem to work at all ugh

Comment: @Dazzlerthe image was posted by me not JaromandaX :) I changed the function name from `sq` to `s`

Comment: @adiga I want to bang my head now, I've fully read about the alternative to math.floor on another stackoverflow page and the one you've used but I just can't seem to keep it with equal to or less than 39 characters at all

Comment: @Dazzler but this code is exactly 39 characters. Run `"s=n=>(r=>(r-~~r<.5?0:1)- -~~r)(n/(1/n))".length` in browser's console.

Comment: @adiga If I were to remove the double minus and add in the plus sign, it would show an error again for me because I used the plus sign but I can manage the character count control

Comment: @adiga the code is 39 characters but the function name is required to be "sq" but yours are s

Comment: which means that if I add in another q to give them their satisfied function name, my character count would be 40 and I would fail again. but Somehow your image seems to work while my doesn't

Comment: @Dazzler As you can see in the screenshot, I have changed the name to `s` and changed the function name in the "Sample tests" section as well (Also, please stop tagging JaromandaX lol. That screenshot was uploaded by me)

Comment: Oh my god I am really so dumb,I forgot to check the sample test! This is new thing for me, very crucial when I'm solving these types of one lines katas'

Comment: Thank you very much, now the problem is fully solved! @adiga

Comment: @adiga and I'm sorry the tag for Jaromanda,since I'm new to this website and this is my very first question, I had a hard time knowing who was who

Comment: @adiga oh btw, it works if I change the name of the function in the sample test and then run it but it wouldn't work if I were to attempt it. But since I do not want to bother anymore, I'll just give up. But thank you very much for your help!

P.S Through this I was able to understand the alternate of math.floor 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985811/alternative-for-math-round

Comment: @Dazzler yeah, I kinda suspected that. Didn't think they would allow to change the test case. Otherwise everyone would be asserting if true equals true. Will try to salvage a character when I'm free.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well

```js
function multiply(a) {
  return a / (1 / a);
}

console.log(multiply(6))
console.log(multiply(4))
```

**The repeat() method returns a new string with a specified number of copies of the string it was called on.** See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

This approach is limited to positive and integer numbers only.

```js
// Another method

function multiplytwo(a) {
  return ("i").repeat(a).repeat(a).length
}


console.log(multiplytwo(4))
console.log(multiplytwo(25))

//creating a string “i” and repeating it “a” times, then repeats that “a” times, and then returning the length.
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because we're supposed to only accept 1 input at the parameter

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for numbers like 4.3 where it will round the number to 16 instead of 19

Answer (score 1):

`**` is not in your list, so you might be able to use it:

```js
sq = n => n ** 2



console.log(sq(5));
```

You could also use `-` twice, instead of `+`:

```js
sq=n=>{s=0;for(let i=n;i>0;i--)s=s-(-n);return s}

console.log(sq(5));
```

(function definition is 49 characters)

Comment: I forgot to mention that ** is not allowed as well and I'm really sorry but the character count is 54 characters actually. This is still a great way by using - instead of + but it doesn't seem to accept it

Comment: Check again - `'sq=n=>{s=0;for(let i=n;i>0;i--)s=s-(-n);return s}'.length === 49`

Comment: This problem is actually from a site called codewars and I have been pulling out my hairs for 3 days until I've decided to ask for help. 
Here is the link to the original task: https://www.codewars.com/kata/one-line-task-square-a-number-without-star-plus-or-math-dot-pow/train/javascript 
Thank you for your work!

Comment: I've just added the link to the website so you might as well try it out. and the code you sent again didn't seem to work

Comment: Whenever I try to run anything on that site, it tells me `Missing language` even when I select Javascript at the top. The site appears to have problems. Just press "Run code snippet" here on SO, you'll see that it squares as expected

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's a very resource, i use it a lot, i don't get any such problem, even though you may find many repeated question as it Open-Source but still it's good

Comment: @CodeManiac Maybe it's because I've never been to the site before, or because I haven't signed up for it, so something isn't loading properly, not sure

Comment: Yeah you need to answer a simple question before you sign up, than you will not see that thing again

Comment: Please try it out! I'm just a beginner learning coding for about 3-4 months and trying to solve my problems on that site because it's a great one!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs a solution that passes tests.
@adiga's solution works nicely. But if you need to be under 39 characters you can exploit JS implicit type coercion: substitute `r-~~r<.5?0:1` by `r-~~r<.5`. It will give you a boolean which will be coerced to either 1 or 0. So, final solution is following:
`s=n=>(r=>(r-~~r<.5)- -~~r)(n/(1/n))`

Answer (score 0):

As this just got brought back up, here is a 22-character solution:

```js
sq=n=>~~-(-.5-n/(1/n))

;[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4.4, 19], [-4.44, 20], [32768, 1073741824]]
  .forEach (([n, s]) => console .log (`sq(${n}) == ${s} //=> ${sq(n) == s}`))
```

### Explanation

Like other answers here it takes advantage of the fact that `n / (1/n)` is mathematically equivalent to squaring `n`.  This is also helped by the fact that although `1 / 0` is `Infinity`, `0 / Infinity` gives back `0`.  Mathematically this is iffy, but for the problem it's perfect.  The trick is then to round this to the nearest integer.  We could do so like this:

```js
let sq = (n) => Math .round(n / (1 /n) + 0.5)
```

But we have two issues here.  First we take the fact that `Math.round` is disallowed by the rules.  Here we can use a common substitution for `Math.round`, namely `~~`.  This is simply two consecutive applications of the [bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT), which first removes any fractional part to convert the result to a 32-bit integer, then inverts all the bits.  Doing it a second time acts much like integer truncation, giving something more like:

```js
let sq = (n) => ~~ (n / (1 /n) + 0.5)
```

But we still have a `+` in the definition, also disallowed.  But that can be replaced by subtracting the negation of the value, with a version like this:

```js
let sq = (n) => ~~ (n / (1 /n) - -0.5)
```

Now, minifying this would give us

```js
sq=(n)=>~~(n/(1/n)- -.5)
```

and this is an equivalent 22-character solution.  But for some reason I really didn't like the space in that version, and since `(a - b)` is equivalent to `- (b - a)`, we can create this alternative:

```js
let sq=n=>~~-(-.5-n/(1/n))
```

---

I'm not generally much of a code-golfer.  I simply don't see the point.  But this was a fun little challenge.